# Can I put 700x32 tyres on my Avanti Blade?

Tags: tire, frames, touring

I'm kitting out my 2006 Avanti Blade for some touring in Tasmania, and the tyres need replacing. Currently they've got some 700x28's on there, but I want to go a bit thicker for touring in case I need to go off road at all. The bike is similar to [this](http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/dianella/bicycles/2008-avanti-blade-sport-road-bike-needs-some-work-/1135068618).

Will the frame handle these in the [32's](http://www.wiggle.com.au/lifeline-road-commute-folding-tyre/)?

Cheers,

James

Comment: This is the frame, incase anyone can recognise it: (Can't find any specs on the 'net.) [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r5dsydd3fsoKYBRLcWDzHV82-svmVos5bw)

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking see [ask] also. We have several similar questions here; access the Desktop version of the site and you'll see related questions on the right hand side of the page. I'd expect that this question will be found to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got 28 mm tyres on there already, you should be better placed to tell than anyone who hasn't already fitted 32s.  Just check that there's a few mm clearance at the sides and top/front (in theory you only need 2mm extra either side but you need a little spare room for flexing, different tyres coming up a diffewrent size etc.).  From [Sheldon Brown's width table](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) you can see it would be a rare rim that couldn't fit 32s if it could fit 28s, and he admits the table is rahter cautious anyway.